# Меню навигации в стиле аккордеон

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Надо сделать меню на сайт в стиле аккордеон. Как я понимаю, его можно реализовать на javacript/jquery. Может кто-нибудь посоветовать, как сделать?

Comment: У этого меню есть огромный минус - оно не показывает пункт, в котором находится пользователь.

Answer (score 4):

Это меню в стиле **аккордеон**. Зная основы jQuery, несложно и самому, но в инете полно готовых решений. Вот, например:

1. [Несколько вариантов](http://efimov.ws/main/develop/javascript/menus-accordion.html)
2. [Простой аккордеон](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/251/Simple-JQuery-accordion-Collapsing-menu)
3. [С небольшим эффектом](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/61/jQuery-Colorful-Content-accordion-menu)

**Добавлено из комментария.**

```js
var mainNav = $('#navigation > ul > li > a');
$('#navigation > ul > li > ul').hide();

$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

mainNav.click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle(1000, 'swing');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navigation {
  width: 200px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background: #036;
  color: #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#navigation ul > li > ul > li > a {
  background: #CCC;
  color: #036;
  border-top: 1px solid #036;
}
#navigation ul > li > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 1.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 1.2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 1.3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 1.4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 1.5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 1.6</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 1.7</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 1.8</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Пункт 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 2.2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 2.3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 2.4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 3.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 3.2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">подпункт 3.3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: У аккордеона другая физика (на если открыть пару и закрыть один, видно), это не совсем то.

Comment: Ну, если жизненно необходимо именно такое меню, то снимите скрипт с того сайта. Проблем то на пять минут...

Comment: Уже думал, проблем куча. Все скрипты в каком то одном файле, очень много чего напиханно, плюс в сайтостроении я еще новичек((

Comment: Набросал вам [свой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/BJzvR/)

Comment: Deonis, спасибо, но я скопировал код, подключил jquery последнюю, но на локалке все меню отображается раскрытым, выпадения/сжатия не работают, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Подкатегории изначально заключены в **div** со стилем display: none;

    <div id="categories_articles" style="display:none">

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо вам огромное.